# Handle show action if no record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, comfortable-mexican-sofa

So I am using a CMS and have campaigns that are at the root domain.  This works perfectly if there is a campaign or a CMS page picks it up but if there are neither pages I get a Template is Missing Error (since my show actually does a redirect to that campaigns donation process).  Anyway to fix this Template is Missing error?  If I rescue within the controller then it won't hit the CMS and if I have the CMS routes first it will hit a 404 before hitting the campaigns controller.

controller

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_campaign

  def show
  end

  protected

  def find_campaign
    begin
      campaign = Campaign.friendly.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to donate_index_path(campaign_id: (campaign.id if campaign.active?)), method: :post
    rescue
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Cwi::Application.routes.draw do
  # ...
  resources :campaigns, only: :show, path: '/'

  comfy_route :cms_admin, :path => '/admin'

  root :to => "cms/content#show"

  comfy_route :cms, :path => '/', :sitemap => false
end
```

Comment: would `if Campaign.friendly.exists?(params[:id])` etc work?

Comment: @Niall are you saying to use that instead of the begin rescue block?

Comment: yes. the exists? method will check if that record exists, so you can handle if it doesn't exist, but at the same time, it'll still reach there. It's hard to tell what ' If I rescue within the controller then it won't hit the CMS and if I have the CMS routes first it will hit a 404 before hitting the campaigns controller.' means though.